# How can I download android project subrepository?

Tags: git

I'd like to download all of enclosed folders from the following URL:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/refs/heads/master/chips#

Now, I understand if it's `git` repo, I use `git clone ...`, `svn` and `hg` by using `checkout` command. But, I don't know how to download this one?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **[root page of the website you provided](https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML)**:

> To clone one of these repositories, install git, and run:
>
> ```
> git clone https://android.googlesource.com/name
> ```

Replace *name* with the repository name, in your case, I think it's `platform/frameworks/ex`